# SQL Dev: Updating column from another table's column with where statement

Tags: sql-update

I have the following 2 table examples (large databases with many more columns)

table1

```
Dirty1     code

Ne yok     553
Bufflo     5767
Ne yok     -345
Tchicgo    -35
Albunny    543
Dtroit     -443
Bufflo     -4534
Matatan    -45
Ne yok     -345
```

table 2

```
Dirty2      Standardized
Manhatahn   Manhattan
Ne yok      New York
Matatan     Manhattan
Brocklyn    Brooklyn
Albunny     Albany
Bufflo      Buffalo
Baffalow    Buffalo
```

I want to update table 1 with the standardized city format in table 2 where table1.dirty1 = table2.dirty2 and code is < 0

so the output should look like the following

output table1

```
Dirty1      code
Ne yok      553
Bufflo      5767
New York    -345
Tchicgo    -35
Albunny     543
Dtroit     -443
Buffalo     -4534
Manhattan   -45
New York    -345
```

I also want to make sure any that don't have a standardized form in the table 2 get skipped (example: Dtroit and tchicgo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: for Oracle-

```
UPDATE table1 SET table1.Dirty1= (SELECT table2.Standardized FROM table2 
                WHERE table1.Dirty1=table2.Dirty2)
WHERE table1.code<0 AND EXISTS (SELECT table2.Standardized FROM table2 
                WHERE table1.Dirty1=table2.Dirty2);
```

Note I'm not using Oracle and haven't tested it but it should work.

This should do the trick (MS-SQL)-

```
UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.Dirty1=table2.Dirty2 SET 
table1.Dirty1=table2.Standardized WHERE table1.code<0;
```

Comment: I'm receiving a missing set keyword error from this query. Is the set keyword misplaced?

Comment: are you using MS-SQL? MySQL?

Comment: sql-developer actually